# Custom plugin in MVVMCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm working on MVVMCross v3 and I want to create my own plugin, I followed this tutorial (which is for the vNext)

http://slodge.blogspot.fr/2012/10/build-new-plugin-for-mvvmcrosss.html

To be compatible for the v3 I changed IMvxServiceConsumer and GetService to Mvx.Resolve.

But on the tutorial there are :

Then, for WinRT, WindowsPhone and MonoTouch clients, you also need to provide a Loader accessor in setup.cs - like:

```
protected override void AddPluginsLoaders(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Platform.MvxLoaderPluginRegistry loaders)

{
    loaders.AddConventionalPlugin<MyCompany.MvvmCross.Plugins.Mega.WindowsPhone.Plugin>();

    base.AddPluginsLoaders(loaders);
}
```

How can I do that in v3?

Thanks

Comment: sorry - not sure you noticed that I did update the answer to the other question with some links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write a new plugin, then :

- the up-to-date sample is https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/GoodVibrations
- there are some notes on this sample in https://speakerdeck.com/cirrious/plugins-in-mvvmcross

For plugin initialisation, the nuget packages now do this via bootstrap files - e.g. see the files added for Location at:

- (WinRT, WinPhone, Droid) -  https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-08-Location/Location.Droid/Bootstrap/LocationPluginBootstrap.cs
- (Touch) - https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-08-Location/Location.Touch/Bootstrap/LocationPluginBootstrap.cs

---

The bootstrap way is the normal way to do initialisation now.

If you did want to use a non-bootstrap technique then you can do this:

- In WinRT, WinPhone, and Droid, you don't need to use a loader, but you do need to call `MyPlugin.PluginManager.Instance.EnsureLoaded` before the plugin can be used.
- In Touch, you would need to provide a loader during `protected override void AddPluginsLoaders(MvxLoaderPluginRegistry loaders)` - **and** you'd then still need to call `EnsureLoaded()` before the plugin can be used.

For examples of this 'old way' of working, see `Setup.cs` in the UI projects in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20TwitterSearch

Comment: Thanks, it works with the up to date sample :)

Now If I want to move the project Sample.Plugin.Vibration.WindowsPhone into a simple folder in my Windows Phone app, it is possible?

Comment: That comment - moving a project into a folder in an app - makes zero sense to me. If a question is worth asking, please ask it properly - it'll save both of us time. Thanks :)