# How can I use async in an mvvmcross view model?

Tags: c#, async-await, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a long running process in an mvvmcross viewmodel and wish to make it async (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).

The async keyword is currently supported in the beta channel for Xamarin.

Below is an example of how I'm currently implementing async. The IsBusy flag ccould be bound to a UI element and display a loading message.

Is this the correct way?

```
public class MyModel: MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private bool _isBusy;

    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return _isBusy; }
        set { _isBusy = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsBusy); ; }
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(DoMyCommand);
        }
    }

    public MyModel(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public async void DoMyCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                _myService.LongRunningProcess();
            });
        IsBusy = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should avoid `async void`. When you're dealing with `ICommand`, you do need to use `async void`, but its scope should be minimized.

This modified code exposes your action as an `async Task`, which is unit testable and consumable from other parts of your code:

```
public class MyModel: MvxViewModel
{
  private readonly IMyService _myService;
  private bool _isBusy;

  public bool IsBusy
  {
    get { return _isBusy; }
    set { _isBusy = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => IsBusy); ; }
  }

  public ICommand MyCommand
  {
    get
    {
      return new MvxCommand(async () => await DoMyCommand());
    }
  }

  public MyModel(IMyService myService)
  {
    _myService = myService;
  }

  public async Task DoMyCommand()
  {
    IsBusy = true;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
      _myService.LongRunningProcess();
    });
    IsBusy = false;
  }
}
```

Your use of `IsBusy` is fine; that's one common approach in asynchronous UIs.

I did change `Task.Factory.StartNew` to `Task.Run`; `Task.Run` is preferred in `async` code for [reasons described by Stephen Toub](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Comment: Since I posted this I've removed the IsBusy flag and added calls to an IAlertsService. This helps centralise the loading/alert logic and removes it from individual views.

Comment: This works fine:  

     return new MvxCommand(() => DoMyCommand());

Comment: The `async` lambda gives you slightly different error handling. With `() => DoMyCommand()`, any exceptions from `DoMyCommand` are silently swallowed. With `async () => await DoMyCommand()`, any exceptions from `DoMyCommand` are treated as unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @ChrisKoiak, can you give an example of how you implement and use an IAlertService in a blog post or article or just a conceptual explanation here?

Comment: @Shawn try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788164/custom-plugin-in-mvvmcross

Comment: @StephenCleary you rock! but i have a question, should we use this code when using async commands or should we need to implement https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx? what's the differences? Thanks!

Comment: @Vackup: I tend to follow the simple pattern in this answer until I need something more complex. A custom "async command" can handle some use cases better: busy spinners / disabled-when-executing, cancellation commands, data binding results/errors. [My latest async command stuff is here](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async/tree/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Async).

Comment: Thanks a lot @StephenCleary! now everything is clear!

Answer (score 6):

MvvmCross now has `MvxAsyncCommand` (see GitHub [commit](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/997/commits/a96505389c58f99e0bcb2a34ab7531e60b2a142e)).

So instead of doing this

```
public ICommand MyCommand
{
  get
  {
    return new MvxCommand(async () => await DoMyCommand());
  }
}
```

You can do this

```
public ICommand MyCommand
{
  get
  {
    return new MvxAsyncCommand(DoMyCommand);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `Async` as suggested by `async` methods naming convention: `return new MvxAsyncCommand(DoMyCommandAsync);`

Answer (score 4):

Looks OK except I would add a try catch finally around that await.

```
    public async void DoMyCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        try{
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                        {
                _myService.LongRunningProcess();
            });
        }catch{
            //Log Exception
        }finally{
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

Further more I have an example on my blog using an MvxCommand with async. Very similar to your example http://deapsquatter.blogspot.com/2013/03/updating-my-mobile-apps-for-async.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **[MethodBinding](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#rio)** [plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugin.MethodBinding/) to avoid boiler plate code (commands), and bind your UI directly to the async method.

Besides, if you use [Fody PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged), your code would look like this:

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class MyModel: MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;

    public bool IsBusy { get; set; }

    public MyModel(IMyService myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
                _myService.LongRunningProcess();
        });
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

You can make the binding like: "Click DoSomething".

On the other hand, rather than using `await Task.Factory.StartNew()`, why not making `_myService.LongRunningProcess` async?
It would look much better:

```
public async Task DoSomething()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    await _myService.LongRunningProcess();
    IsBusy = false;
}
```